# How to export dsym file from xcarchive on terminal

Tags: ios, swift, jenkins, terminal, ditto

I'm getting archive and IPA on Jenkins. I want to upload my dsym to Fabric after I get the build. As you know, `xcodebuild` generates dsym inside xcarchive/dSYMs folder.

How I get the archive:

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -quiet -workspace My_Project.xcworkspace -scheme My_Project_Test -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release archive -archivePath CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${WORKSPACE}/build/My_Project_Test.xcarchive
```

How I get the IPA:

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${WORKSPACE}/build/My_Project_Test.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist My_Project/Resources/Test/Test_ExportOptions.plist -exportPath CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${WORKSPACE}/build
```

Example code to get the dsym (which is not working at the moment):

```
ditto -c -k --keepParent -rsrc "${WORKSPACE}/build/My_Project_Test.app.dSYM" ${WORKSPACE}/build/My_project_Test-${PRODUCT_VERSION}-${PRODUCT_VERSION}-dSYM.zip
```

Upload code:

```
$WORKSPACE/Pods/Fabric/upload-symbols -a xxxxxxxxxxxx -p ios -- build/My_Project_Test.app.dSYM
```

My question is that how can I export dsym file from xcarchive with ditto code or some equal code.

Comment: You may use Fastlane to make your whole job of CI/CD easier.

Answer (score 7):

I found that we can reach `xcarchive` file directly. So that below code will work to zip dsym file.

```
ditto -c -k --keepParent -rsrc "${WORKSPACE}/build/My_Project_Test.xcarchive/dSYMs/My_Project_Test.app.dSYM" ${WORKSPACE}/build/My_Project_Test-${PRODUCT_VERSION}-${PRODUCT_VERSION}-dSYM.zip
```

Comment: This is perfect. If you don't want a zip of the output, omit `-c -k`. If you want all of the dSYMs in your archive, remove `/My_Project_Test.app.dSYM` from the source path.